# Can I pass the results from match to sh in fastlane?

Tags: fastlane

I have lane like:

```
lane :beta do
  match(type: "appstore")
  sh "ember cdv:build
  --platform ios
  --code-sign-identity='iPhone Distribution: Cannla Pte Ltd (856AP7L2GS)'
  --provisioning-profile='5feb0088-c4dd-4ca2-84e6-4bbf7f319248'
  --release"
  pilot
end
```

Can I get the code signing identity and provisioning profile from match instead of manually setting them like this?

Answer (score 2):

*match* will automatically fill your environment variables. Check out the [fastlane code signing docs](https://docs.fastlane.tools/codesigning/XcodeProject/) on what kind of variables are exposed and how you can use them in your Xcode project.

By default, these are the environment variables that are exposed for you

```
+---------------------+------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
|                                       Installed Provisioning Profile                                        |
+---------------------+------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| Parameter           | Environment Variable                           | Value                                |
+---------------------+------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| App Identifier      |                                                | me.themoji.release                   |
| Type                |                                                | appstore                             |
| Profile UUID        | sigh_me.themoji.beta_appstore                  | 22a19b3a-7cf6-4997-95f2-9cbb4d33fe7e |
| Profile Name        | sigh_me.themoji.beta_appstore_profile-name     | match AppStore me.themoji.release    |
| Development Team ID | sigh_me.themoji.beta_appstore_team-id          | N8XAAASEU2                           |
+---------------------+------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
```